# Find max, min and sum of an array using function

Tags: c

I want to create a programm to find maximum, minimum and summation for a given array, but when I take my code to compiler, it returned `expressed expression before 'int'` and `too few arguments` to all the functions.

And here is my code, please tell me why it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_array(int array[], int len) {
    // print array on screen
    int b;
    printf("Array: ");
for (b = 0; b < len - 1; b++) {
    printf("%d, ", array[b]);
}
if (b >= len - 1) {
    printf("%d\n", array[b]);
}

}

// function
int min(int *x, int len) {
    int mintemp = x[0], i;
    for (i = 1;i < len;i++) {
        if(x[i] < mintemp) {
            mintemp = x[i];
        }
    }
    return mintemp;
}
int max(int *y, int len) {
int maxtemp = y[0], j;
for (j = 1;j < len;j++) {
        if(y[j] > maxtemp) {
            maxtemp = y[j];
        }
    }
    return maxtemp;
}
int sum(int *z, int len) {
    int sumtemp = 0, k;
    for (k = 0;k < len;k++) {
       sumtemp = sumtemp + z[k];
    }
    return sumtemp;
}


int main() {
    int array[] = {3, 9, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 10, 11};
    int len = 11;

    print_array(array, len);
    // print other elements on screen
    printf("Maximum: %d\n", max(int *x, int len));
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", min(int *y, int len));
    printf("Summation: %d\n", sum(int *z, int len));
return 0;

}
```

Comment: at `printf("Maximum: %d\n", max(int *x, int len));`:  `max` call like `max(array, len)`

Comment: `min` and `max` are probably defined already, perhaps as macros in `stdlib`. Use different identifiers, for example `arrmin` and `arrmax`.

Comment: @Ryoine you should use `long unsigned int size = sizeof (array) / sizeof(*array);`  instead of `int len = 11;`  Check this [DEMO](https://ideone.com/Yyquoy) and try to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with calling the functions. Function call in C is like this

`function_name(argument 1, argument 2, argument 3, ......, argument n);`

**There is no need to specifying the data type along the parameters in the call like you were doing in your code.**

Also you were passing pointers `x`, `y` and `z` that do not point to your array.

I have corrected the code as shown below.

```
int main() {
    int array[] = {3, 9, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 10, 11};
    int len = 11;

    print_array(array, len);
    // print other elements on screen
    printf("Maximum: %d\n", max(array, len)); // pass array and len
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", min(array, len));
    printf("Summation: %d\n", sum(array, len));
return 0;

}
```

**If you want to pass the array to functions via pointers you can do it like this.**

```
int main() {
    int array[] = {3, 9, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 4, 10, 11};
    int len = 11;

    int *x = array;
    int *y = array;
    int *z = array;

    print_array(array, len);
    // print other elements on screen
    printf("Maximum: %d\n", max(x, len));
    printf("Minimum: %d\n", min(y, len));
    printf("Summation: %d\n", sum(z, len));
return 0;

}
```

**Also there is no need to declare 3 different pointers and pass it to the functions, you can declare just one and reuse it with subsequent calls.**

Hope this helps.!!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want to try to make to the functions before not included in the main function, but I still don't know how to that

Comment: I didn't get you. You want to have the functions you defined after the main function.?

Comment: I mean I want to try to make the functions min, max and sum not related to the main function

Comment: Relate in the sense, you don't want to call the functions from the `main()` ?

Comment: As you are reading the array in the `main()` you have to pass the array to other functions to work on that array. If you don't want to call the functions directly from the `main()` you can declare some function named like `read_array()` to read the array and call other functions as necessary from that function itself. NB: Don't forget to call the `read_array()` function from the `main()`